includepdf pageref does not point to the first page of a multi-page pdf
I have a rather complicated includepdf command. I insert an A4 multi-page document. I set it to be fitted within a frame, insert a custom caption (which is simply some text). However, I struggled to use \pageref command to refer to the FIRST page of the document. I finally discovered setcounter command. So finally in text I can get the correct page number, yaay, but the hyperlink doesn't work :( Any suggestions how to make pageref below to link correctly to the first pge of the document?
...
\newcounter{pdfpage}

\begin{document}
...

Page \pageref{label-1}.

\setcounter{pdfpage}{0}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper,templatesize={210mm}{297mm},scale=0.9,frame,
picturecommand={\put(18mm,277mm){Custom caption.}}\refstepcounter{pdfpage}\label{label-\thepdfpage}]{multipage.pdf}


\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,pdfpages}
\begin{document}
something before 
\hyperlink{\RefProperty{blub}{pagetarget}}{\RefProperty{blub}{page}}
\clearpage
\RecordProperties{blub}{page,pagetarget}
\includepdf[pages=1-10]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}


Yes that's it, I spent so much time on improving counters and stuff. But this RecordProperties, which I have never used before, seems to do exactly what I need. Cheers

well it is rather new, and I know about it as I wrote part of the code ...
